# Open CV feature detection in GPU

Tags: opencv, image-processing, gpu, feature-detection

I'm using **OpenCV 2.4.6** in a prototype of object detection and I was wondering in how to improve the feature detection/extraction performance. Someone knows if is it possible to run feature detection/extraction/matching, like SIFT/SIFT/BF, or even the findHomography, on **GPU**?

Tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV GPU module contains implementations for FAST, ORB and SURF feature detectors/extractors and for BruteForceMatcher.

You can read more in documentation:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.6/modules/gpu/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.6/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html#gpu-surf-gpu